# How to avoid multiple occurrences on an object?

Tags: jquery, live

I can never get this right - how to avoid multiple occurrences on an object. For instance, I have this function where you can click a **link (go to the top)**, then the document will be scrolled up to the top.

```
this.scrollTop = function(){
    $('a[href=#top]').live('click',function(){
        alert('1');
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });
}
```

The problem is I have an ajax page to be loaded into the same page, and the ajax page has another **link (go to the top)** as well, so I have to attach that `scrollTop` function again after the ajax call.

Then the existing **link (go to the top)** will occur twice when I check with the alert - how can I fix it?

1. [the scrolltop plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/2bx7W/1/).
2. [the plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/YPE37/) to load an ajax page.
3. [the live example](http://lauthiamkok.net/dump/mls/projects.php).

If you click the first test thumbnail image on the left to load the ajax page, then you go to the bottom of the document to click **go to the top**, then you see it alert twice or more depends how many times you call the ajax page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `live`, you don't have to attach handlers anymore. From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, **now and in the future**.

Just place

```
$('a[href=#top]').live('click',function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

in your main file.

The event handler is attached to the root of the DOM. It listens to all `click` events. Whenever an element is clicked that matches the selector (`a[href=#top]`), the handler is executed.

---

[Here is a very simplistic example](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/XWst4/). You will see that `$('div').live(...)` is only called *once* but the handler will be called for every element you add later.

---

**Update:**

How about giving the "go to top" links in the articles a different href?

```
$('a[href=#article]').live('click',function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:100}, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

and use `#top` only for the main one. In this you don't have to use `live` anymore I think, you can attach the handler directly:

```
$('a[href=#top]').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: then I have to attach that chunk of code again after the ajax call - I don't think it is a good idea. I would like to make it into a function or a plugin so that I can attach it as a handler. thanks.

Comment: @lauthiamkok: No you don't have to do that. That is the whole point of using `live`. You call `$(...).live()` **once** and it will execute the handler for every element that matches the selector, no matter whether it already exists or not. That you don't have to assign handlers to newly created elements. I added an example. I hope it makes it clearer. You think too complicated ;)

Comment: @felix: thanks. I have to change the value of `scrollTop` after the ajax call so I think this code has to be dynamic. maybe I should not use `live` but `click` instead? but `click` has the same problem as `live`.

Comment: @lauthiamkok: I think you some logic error here. What do you attach `scrollTop` to? If you have to change that function, should the previously bound elements use the new function or the old one? If `scrollTop` is already an event handler, why do attach an event handler *inside* the event handler? Please provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @felix: sorry I meant this value of `scrollTop:0` will be changed to `scrollTop:100` after my ajax call.

Comment: @lauthiamkok: So these links are actually not equivalent? They make the page scroll to different positions? Where does 100 come from? How do you determine that value?

Comment: @felix: `How about giving the "go to top" links in the articles a different href?` yes it is the next best answer. I will probably go for this if I can work out the first best answer! lol

Comment: @lauthiamkok: It is actually the best solution. The `href` should point to an id of an element anyway. In this case you want to go to the top of the article, so it makes totally sense to do so.

Comment: @felix: cool. I will go for that. thanks for your help and advice! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I use it on `$.ajax` function on the final. In my case fail, I use 500 in order to delay it and stop to resend many times.

```
}).fail(function(response, status){
    alert("FAILED: "+JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
},500);
```

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Before attaching the function to 'click' event type of the selector, use unbind to unbind previous click events. Here is how you can unbind:

```
$(selector).unbind('click');
```